# Calculate time a web page will take to load into UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, httpwebrequest, http-headers

How can we calculate the time that a web page will take to load into a `UIWebView`? If you suggest looking at the HTTP content-length header, then how can this be done when the HTTP header doesn't have content-length. I want to make a progress bar tracking the loading time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, you don't know when the HTTP stream will end if you don't have a content length. You can detect when a document finishes loading using the UIWebView notifications. However, without content length, you can't have a progress bar.

Comment: actually i have an app in my iPhone which is doing the same thing for those web url's which doesn't have content-length, do you have any idea how they are doing that? url - http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/downloads-lite-download-manager/id349275540?mt=8

Comment: One guess would be to use the data itself. MP3 files, avi files, zip files, etc all have data in their headers. It's individual to each file type, but it should be pretty easy to find code to get the size of a zip file or an MP3 file from its header block. You might not be able to do it in a UIWebView though, can't remember if that gives you access to data as the page is loading. Using the headers method, you would typically need the first 4-8 KB of the data to read information about the file.